# tikz based font package - no need for font installation

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, installing

As I understand, if one wants to add a font package to latex for example bbm one also needs to install the fonts in the computer separately.
so I thought of the option to create latex fonts using tikz package . so there will be no need to install additional fonts on the computer. the only thing to add to latex file would be the font package based on tikz

Comment: Oh no. Please no. That's not how things work but still even it is possible no.

Comment: there is a _lot_ of difference between lines drawn by a package such as tikz and a font, even if the lines drawn are in the shape of letters.

Comment: You don't have to install the fonts as well as the package. The fonts are either part of the package or, if you want to use arbitrary fonts installed for your computer generally, you don't need a special package but something like **fontspec** and XeTeX or LuaTeX. But for traditional TeX fonts and those in type1 format, the fonts are installed along with everything else in your TeX distribution. You don't have to also install fonts somewhere else.